# Listview is not visible on Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I can't see my listview on Activity after adding a list item dynamically on floatingAction button click.
When I click on floatingActionButton, a new activity opens up which takes my input, after clicking on the save button ReminderActivity opens up but did not show input passed added in the list.

My motive is to add a new item in the `listView` every time after getting data from **ReminderInputDataActivity** which opens when I click on floating action button.

```
public class ReminderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lvReminder;
    private FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
    private ArrayList<Reminder> reminders;
    public static final String REMINDER_INPUT = "reminder_input";
    private ReminderCustomAdapter reminderListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder);

        reminders = new ArrayList<>();
        lvReminder = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvReminder);
        Intent getIntent = getIntent();
        String[] reminderInput = getIntent.getStringArrayExtra(REMINDER_INPUT);
        if (reminderInput != null) {
            reminders.add(new Reminder(reminderInput[0], reminderInput[1], reminderInput[2]));
        }
        reminderListAdapter = new ReminderCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_reminder, reminders);
        lvReminder.setAdapter(reminderListAdapter);

        floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ReminderActivity.this, ReminderInputDataActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (reminderListAdapter != null) {
            reminderListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Reminder {

    private String title;
    private String date;
    private String time;

    public Reminder() {
    }

    public Reminder(String title, String date, String time) {
        this.title = title;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

```
public class ReminderInputDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etReminderTitle;
    private Button btDate, btTime;
    public static final String REMINDER_INPUT = "reminder_input";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.input_reminder);

        etReminderTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etReminderTitle);
        btDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btReminderDate);
        btTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btReminderTime);
        btDate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()));
        btTime.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()));
        Button btRemSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btRemSave);
        Button btRemCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btRemCancel);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(ReminderInputDataActivity.this, ReminderActivity.class);
        btRemSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String[] userInput = new String[3];
                userInput[0] = etReminderTitle.getText() != null ? etReminderTitle.getText().toString() : "";
                userInput[1] = btDate.getText().toString();
                userInput[2] = btTime.getText().toString();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putStringArray(REMINDER_INPUT, userInput);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btRemCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class ReminderCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;
    private int resource;
    private ArrayList<Reminder> reminderList;

    public ReminderCustomAdapter(Context mContext, int resource, ArrayList<Reminder> reminderList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.reminderList = reminderList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
        TextView tvInputRemTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvInputRemTitle);
        TextView tvInputRemDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvInputRemDate);
        TextView tvInputRemTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvInputRemTime);

        Reminder reminder = reminderList.get(position);
        tvInputRemTitle.setText(reminder.getTitle());
        tvInputRemDate.setText(reminder.getDate());
        tvInputRemTime.setText(reminder.getTime());
        return view;
    }
}
```

**activity_reminder.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvReminder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:contentDescription="@string/reminder"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/fab_3_rounded" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**listview_reminder.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInputRemTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInputRemDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvInputRemTitle"
        android:hint="Date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInputRemTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvInputRemTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvInputRemDate"
        android:hint="Time" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am new to android and started creating a basic project, for the above issue I watched some videos and go through articles but unable to get the issue here.

Please help. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is due to this code

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(ReminderInputDataActivity.this, ReminderActivity.class);
    btRemSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String[] userInput = new String[3];
            userInput[0] = etReminderTitle.getText() != null ? etReminderTitle.getText().toString() : "";
            userInput[1] = btDate.getText().toString();
            userInput[2] = btTime.getText().toString();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putStringArray(REMINDER_INPUT, userInput);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Here you start `ReminderActivity` again which calls `onCreate` method of this activity, where you have added `reminders = new ArrayList<>();` which recreate this arraylist with no data.
To Avoid this you can implement two solutions.

1. Implement `interface`.
2. `StartActivityForResult`.

Easiest solution would be `StartActivityForResult`.
For Example,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ReminderActivity.this,ReminderInputDataActivity.class);  
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2); 

and in the same activity implement the callback.

@Override  
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
   {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
    // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
    if(requestCode==2)  
    {  
     String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
     textView1.setText(message);  
     }  
 }
```

From ReminderInputDataActivity send data back to this class like this.

```
  Intent intent=new Intent();  
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  
                setResult(2,intent);  
                finish();//finishing activity
```